# In Pylon C# How to Change frameMode to Trigger?

Tags: pylons, basler

i want to grab image only when get trigger signal so i have to change basler camera's frameMode to Trigger mode

```
        hDev = Pylon.CreateDeviceByIndex((uint)0);
        Pylon.DeviceFeatureFromString(hDev, "TriggerSelector", "FrameStart");
        Pylon.DeviceFeatureFromString(hDev, "TriggerMode", "On");
```

this code got System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Error ...

Answer (score 0):

Open the camera first:

```
PylonDeviceOpen( hDev, PYLONC_ACCESS_MODE_CONTROL | PYLONC_ACCESS_MODE_STREAM )
```

Btw, are you're trying to use pylon C API in managed .NET environment? Looks like bad idea, use .NET interface for it directly:
https://docs.baslerweb.com/pylonapi/net/Samples#grab